# Inserting a formula using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am needing to insert a formula in using vba coding.

at the moment the line of code is

```
=IF(
    AND(
        Compliance="No",
        OR(
            Delivery <> "",
            C31 <> ""
        )
    ),
    "Please Delete Compliance Data",
    IF(
        AND(
            E11="",
            E13="",
            E23="",
            E25="",
            E26="",
            E28="",
            E30="",
            E31=""),
        VLOOKUP(C15,'Extrapolated RV Calculator'!B:S,18,0),
        "Please complete form / SC request"
    )
)"
```

It seems to error out on the text portions inside the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have quotes inside a string then you need to escape them by doubling them up `s = "a string with ""quotes"" in it"`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to
Range("RV").Formula = "=IF(AND(Compliance=""No"",OR(Delivery<>"""",C31<>"""")),""Please Delete Compliance Data"",IF(AND(E11="""",E13="""",E23="""",E25="""",E26="",E28="""",E30="""",E31=""""),VLOOKUP(C15,'Extrapolated RV Calculator'!B:S,18,0),""Please complete form / SC request""))"

But it comes up with 400 in a VBA error box

Comment: If you assign the formula to a variable and Debug.print it, can you copy the output from the Immediate window and paste it into the cell without any error?  If it gives you an error, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for all your help Tim, the error was on E13, where I stil only had 1 set of brackets.

Comment: my experience with inserting formulas is to break them into very simple pieces (across several cells) at least to start with, and get the pieces working independently. Tim's suggestion is also a best practice IMO

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly when you post it on SO - it makes it a lot easier for everyone involved. You can always post a "copy paste" version of it for people to copy into excel, but anyone trying to reason through that will have a hard time

Comment: What you have in your question is not vba, this is the cell formula. This doesn't seem right. Also there is a `"` at the end of your code? Also does this code work in Excel and not vba, or not in both?

Comment: What is `Range("RV").Formula` in your comment? Should this be `Range("R13").Formula` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Here are four ways to use quotation marks inside strings in VBA:

- Replace "" with Chr$(34).  34 is the ASCII code for quotation marks
- Use String(2,Chr$(34)) to make double quotes
- Use two double quotation marks for every one (per Tim's comment)
- Replace two double quotation marks with a different method, like ISBLANK for worksheet functions.

None of these is better.  I usually use two double quotation marks to escape them.  But sometimes I get so many quotation marks together that it's hard to read and maintain, so I'll use a different method.  Here's an example:

```
Dim aFormula(1 To 5) As String

aFormula(1) = "=IF(AND(Compliance=""No"",OR(Delivery<>" & String(2, Chr$(34))
aFormula(2) = ",C31<>" & String(2, Chr$(34)) & ") ),"
aFormula(3) = Chr$(34) & "Please Delete Compliance Data" & Chr$(34)
aFormula(4) = ",IF(AND(ISBLANK(E11),ISBLANK(E13),ISBLANK(E23),ISBLANK(E25),ISBLANK(E26),ISBLANK(E28),ISBLANK(E30),ISBLANK(E31)),"
aFormula(5) = "VLOOKUP(C15,'Extrapolated RV Calculator'!B:S,18,0),""Please complete form / SC request""))"

Sheet1.Range("R13").Formula = Join(aFormula, vbNullString)
```

Answer (score 0):

To empower you for the future I strongly recommend you do the following when you want to use functionality in Excel in your VBA code that you are not acquainted with yet.

Go to the developer menu and press the record macro button.

Now fill in a formula in a cell, Clear a cells content by pressing delete and clearing a cells content by going into the cell and deleting all the characters and press enter.

Now stop the macro. And go to the VBA window. See how the code is structured to accomplish these things.

Apply this also whenever you want to do other things to get a good idea of what you can use to get the results you want without having to browse around on the internet for ages!

Also watch the local variables in the locals window or Debug.Print the string you try to build to see hwat it looks so far