# Setting cell formula which includes "text constants" in Excel cell by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**In actual cell formula I can manually set the following formula.**
=IF(MONTH(A15)<7,"FY "&YEAR(A15)-1&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(A15),2),"FY "&YEAR(A15)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(A15)+1,2))

**I am trying to set this formula by vba using the following code.**
ActiveCell.formulaR1C1 = "=IF(MONTH(A15)<7,"FY "&YEAR(A15)-1&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(A15),2),"FY "&YEAR(A15)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(A15)+1,2))"

The VBA compiler displays a compile error: Expected: end of statement. This appears to have a problem with the exclamation marks.

Does anyone now how to include a text constant in a cell formula set by vba code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a formula using Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513529/inserting-a-formula-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes within the string like so:

```
ActiveCell.formulaR1C1 = "=IF(MONTH(A15)<7,""FY ""&YEAR(A15)-1&""/""&RIGHT(YEAR(A15),2),""FY ""&YEAR(A15)&""/""&RIGHT(YEAR(A15)+1,2))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You only use FormulaR1C1 if you pass a reference in R1C1 format, but you're using A1 format. You can also shorten that formula if you wish:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=""FY ""&YEAR(A15)-(MONTH(A15)<7)&""/""&RIGHT(YEAR(A15)+(MONTH(A15)>=7),2)"
```